# return to origin target after routing to loginpage using $routeChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-routing

i'm implementing an login-form to my single page angularjs application.
An `$routeChangeStart` listener watches for route changes. If the user start the application or moves from one route to an other, the application will check, if the user is logged in and -if not- the user will be routed to the login-page.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {
        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log('DENY, go to login-page');
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.path('/login');
        }
        else {
            console.log('ALLOW');
            $location.path('/main'); //main is not correct in every case
        }
    });
}]);
```

The `Auth` factory handles the information, if the user is logged in.

If the user is logged in, the new path is `main` -> `$location.path('/main');`.

But: I don't need an fixed target after login. What I need is an dynamic target depending on the origin target of the user.

Example: new user is on `/main` and clicks to `/details` -> `$routeChangeStart` is fired and the user is routed to `/login`. After an valid login, the user should be back to `/details`, because this was the target he likes to go.

The problem is: insight the login page/controller, I have no information about the real target of the user.

I know, bevore routing to `/login`, the `next` parameter has the Information about the real target of the user and all parameters, which needed to render the target-page (like `/details`, what is in real: `/details/:ID/....`).

Should I pass those informations (`next.originalPath`, `next.params`) as routing parameter to `/login` in order to redirect from the loginpage after login is successful? Or should I store those informations insight the `Auth` service (don't think, that this is the right place), so there are available everywhere?

What is the best way, to return the user to his origin route target after login?

Answer (score 0):

use otherwise method. Put there $injector, and put ther $state

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise ($injector) ->
    $state = $injector.get('$state')
```

write an interceptor, witch recognize what reqest has become, and redirect user. injector should hold data that are need

```
this.loginAction= (redirect) ->
     $location = $injector.get('$location')
      $location.path('login')
this.loggedAction= (redirect) ->
      $state = $injector.get('$state')
     $state.go();
```

Answer (score 0):

in my current project, we save the real target to an angular service. and after successful login we check if that service contains a redirect url. if it exists redirect to URL otherwise to home page.

here is sample code, note: we are using ui-router

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState , toParams/*, fromState, fromParams*/) {

        // if route requires auth and user is not logged in
        //toState['requiresAuth'] -> contains authorization level
        if (typeof toState['requiresAuth'] === 'string' && !authService.isUserAuthenticated(toState['requiresAuth'])) {
            navService.saveRedirectPage();
            navService.goToLoginPage();
            return;
        }

        currentPage = toState;
    });
```

Navigation Service

```
    navService.saveRedirectPage = function () {
        var nextRouteURL = $location.path();
        storService.setParameter('redirectURL', nextRouteURL);
    };

    //goes to redirect page if possible
    //otherwise goes to home page
    navService.goToRedirectPage = function () {

        if (storService.hasParameter('redirectURL')) {
            var redirectURL = storService.getParameterOnce('redirectURL');
            $location.path(redirectURL);
            return;
        }

        navService.goToHomePage();
    };
```

storService is a simple service that keeps named parameters given to it
here it is

```
(function () {

    angular.module('doktorin.services').factory('StorageService', ['$q',     function ($q) {

    var storageAPI = {};
    var storageData = {};
    var storageWaiters = {};

    var notifyWaiters = function (name, data) {
        if (storageWaiters[name] instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < storageWaiters[name].length; i++) {
                storageWaiters[name][i].resolve(data);
            }
            //reset list
            storageWaiters[name] = null;
        }
    };

    ///returns and deletes parameter for single usage
    storageAPI.getParameterOnce = function (name) {
        var data = storageAPI.getParameter(name);
        storageAPI.deleteParameter(name);
        return data;
    };

    storageAPI.deleteParameter = function (name) {
        delete storageData[name];
    };

    storageAPI.setParameter = function (name, data) {
        storageData[name] = data;
        notifyWaiters(name, data);
    };

    storageAPI.getParameter = function (name) {
        if (!storageAPI.hasParameter(name)) {
            throw 'Invalid parameter get at StorageService with Name: ' + name;
        }

        return storageData[name];
    };

    storageAPI.hasParameter = function (name) {
        return typeof storageData[name] !== 'undefined';
    };

    storageAPI.waitParameter = function (name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (storageAPI.hasParameter(name)) {
            deferred.resolve(storageAPI.getParameter(name));
        } else {

            if ( !(storageWaiters[name] instanceof Array)) {
                storageWaiters[name] = [];
            }

            storageWaiters[name].push(deferred);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return storageAPI;
}]);

})();
```

and here is successful login event

```
 authService.login(me.logCredentials).then(function () {

            navService.goToRedirectPage();
        },
        function (err) {
               //handle error here  

        });
```